# Is there a way to compare multiset iterators?

Tags: c++, multiset

I am wondering if there is a way to compare multiset iterators? I am interested in doing something like the following:

```
    std::multiset<int> mt{1,1,1,1,3,4,5};
    auto it1 = mt.find(3);
    auto it2 = mt.find(1);
    cout << (it1 < it2) << endl; // this should print "0"
    it1 = mt.find(equal_range);
    auto p = mt.equal_range(1);
    cout << (p.first < p.second) << endl; // this should print "1"
```

However I am unable to use the comparison operator on the multiset iterators.

If the values in the set were unique, I could just compare the dereferenced version of the iterators, but I am using multiset specifically because the values may not be unique, and if 2 iterators point to different instances of the same value, I need a way to compare them based on their relative location in the underlying tree.

Comment: It reads as if you want to compare `std::distance(mt.begin(), it)`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to compare multiset iterators?

There's no ordered comparison. Bidirectional iterators aren't generally required/guaranteed to be less-than-comparable.

The problem that you're facing is essentially the same as finding out the order of elements in a linked list. A linear complexity algorithm is possible:

```
 std::distance(std::begin(mt), it1) < std::distance(std::begin(mt), it2)
```

Comparison for equality is trivial.